# Is it reasonable to create a (beta-function) tag? (in the meantime created)

Tags: discussion, tagging

It seems to me that although there is already the [special-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions) tag, it would be interesting to have a tag for the beta function. It would allow to tag this special function too, similarly to what happens to the $\Gamma$ function, which has the [gamma-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamma-function) tag. The tag would also be appropriate for the incomplete beta function.  Some examples I've found are:

- [An integral related to the beta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318828/integral-involving-the-beta-function)
- [Beta integral transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153270/beta-integral-transformation)
- [About the Beta function : $\text{B}\left(\frac{4}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360548/about-the-beta-function-textb-left-frac43-frac23-right)
- [Is there a combinatorial way to see the link between the beta and gamma functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72067/is-there-a-combinatorial-way-to-see-the-link-between-the-beta-and-gamma-function)
- [Using the beta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410445/using-the-beta-function)
- [Gamma and Beta Functions : Integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384464/gamma-and-beta-functions-integration)
- [Beta function derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/beta-function-derivation)
- [An identity involving the Beta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420024/an-identity-involving-the-beta-function)
- [Did Euler have an alpha function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228543/did-euler-have-an-alpha-function)
- [Easy approximation of the incomplete beta function $\text{B}_x(a,b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53925/easy-approximation-of-the-incomplete-beta-function-textb-xa-b)

Are you in favor of the idea of creating the [beta-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-function) tag?

EDIT: I added two possible answers: YES or NO.

UPDATE. This tag has been created in the meantime as answered by Martin Sleziek. I'm in favor of keeping it and retag some older questions.

Comment: I do recall seeing more than ten of these sorts of questions, so I think a specialized tag might be appropriate at this point...

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I don't think this is reasonable. One should then also create cosine- and sine-function separate tags in addition to "exponential function".

Comment: @O.L.  I respect your opinion, but it seems to me that by your argument the ([tag:gamma-function]) tag shouldn't have been created, since *if I remember correct* there was already the ([tag:special-functions]) tag.

Comment: @AméricoTavares This is not quite comparable. Gamma function is much, much more fundamental function then beta, whose (almost) single merit is being a relatively frequently encountered integral.

Comment: @O.L.  I tend to agree with you that the Gamma function is more fundamental than the beta function. I just add that both are Euler integrals.

Comment: The question got a downvote.

Comment: @AméricoTavares The downvote is mine. This was not at all intended to criticize the question, I just had an impression that it is a common practice on meta to support a proposition or not with voting (my question on increase of time limit for comment editing got two downvotes recently). I apologize if it is not so.

Comment: @O.L. You are definitely correct about votes on meta.

Comment: @O.L. Thanks for explaining the meaning of your vote!

Comment: @O.L. I've read the paragraph [Voting is different on meta](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) and concluded that you are correct, as commented by Lord_Farin.

Comment: @O.L., as a counterpoint, we already have [tag:trigonometry], and the trig functions are usually already used together in a question, so there'd be no need to make tags for each of the six (seven? eight?) trig functions, and six more tags for the inverses. (On that note, it was also decided long ago that the hyperbolic functions be also covered under [tag:trigonometry], so we already have a sufficiently wide umbrella...)

Comment: ...my point being, the analogy does not at all match the situation for considering if beta function questions ought to have a tag of their own. Maybe here's a better analogy: should we have separate tags for the usual Bessel functions, and the modified versions? If I had to react to that... I'd be on the fence.

Comment: It seems that it is not reasonable (+5/-4).

Comment: @J.M.: we actually *do* have a [tag:hyperbolic-functions] tag, with a not meager number of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the tag [beta-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-function) was created recently. (The [list of new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) says that it was created on 
Oct 18 at 16:36.) I did not want to create a new meta thread for the same tag, which is why I am bumping this one. (If you think that a new discussion would be better, feel free to create one and I will delete my answer here. But to me the new question would seem almost as a duplicate - since it would ask basically the same question. The only difference is that in the meantime someone created the tag. And additionally, in this way the older discussion about this tag will be more visible than in the case of a new post linking to this one.)

A [tag-excerpt was also created](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/980365/revisions).

> For questions about Beta function, a special function closely related to Gamma. It is advisable to also use [special-functions] tag with this one.

At the moment, the tag has 4 questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972837/log-integrals-ii), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978458/definite-integral-similar-to-beta-function-but-with-exponential-negative-square), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979303/show-that-a-beta-distribution-is-completely-determined-given-mean-and-confidence), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981776/why-does-%ce%b2-%ce%b1-give-a-symmetric-standard-beta-pdf).

Basically I see two problems with this tag:

- The outcome of the voting on this question seems to be that this tag is not needed. (But, of course, the opinion of community can change over time.)
- The tag is not used consistently with the tag excerpt. Some of the questions are about [beta distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/beta-function/info) in probability and statistics. (This was pointed out [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18254844#18254844), I did not even know about this kind of probability distribution.)

The purpose of bumping this post is to start some discussion on:

- Whether the tag should be kept. (In which case we might also retag some older questions.)
- Whether the two meanings in which the tag is used are compatible enough to be in the same tag. (Maybe this would merit a separate meta question...? I have decided not to fragment the discussion about the same tag too much and mention this in the same post.)

Comment: Not to mention Goedel's $\beta$ function in logic, and the general notion of $\beta$ functions encoding sequences of integers in this context.

Comment: I unaccepted one of the answers to bump this question again.

Comment: I'm in favor of keep this tag and retag some older questions.

Answer (score 6):

**NO**, I am not in favor of the idea of creating the [beta-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-function) tag.

Answer (score 4):

**YES**, I am in favor of the idea of creating the [beta-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-function) tag.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks for the corrections!

Answer (score 0):

In view of the existing votes it is not a good idea for the time being.

1. NO: +4/0
2. YES: +2/0
3. question: +5/-4

Edit. I will accept this answer. Now the votes are:

1. NO: +5/0
2. YES: +3/0
3. question: +6/-4

Update. Unaccepted in view of the new answer by Martin Sleziak.